# Populate rich Text box without openFile Dialog C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, richtextbox

Ive been trying for a while now to get a rich textbox to populate from a text file. Normally I would say this is easy and there are tons of solutions on here for it. My only issue is I don't want the open file dialog to populate it I want it to be populated on the onload event of the form, and populate from a known text file on the network drive here. Every solution I find seems to be asking for the users input to open the file I don't want this. This is due to the fact that when the text file is edited( which it will often be) I want the textbox to mimic this rather then have an outdated version hard coded in. Please help

Comment: What UI framework are you using?  Winforms, WPF, Silverlight?

Comment: I am using Windows forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the location then

```
const string Myfile = @"c:\test\myfile.rtf";

richTextBox1.Loadfile(Myfile);
```

you can use UNC etc, but it may error if it cant find the file - so I would suggest file checks etc.

Comment: I tried this but when loading the file it said that the file is not a valid format. Is there an assembly reference I am missing?

Comment: was the file you loaded an rtf file? I tried it on a file I had, worked first time...

Comment: Never mind I am an idiot forgot to save the file as RTF monday mornings got me Thanks this is my soln

Comment: Every day is monday morning for me!

Answer (score 0):

Use System.IO.FileSystemWatcher to watch for changes to the file, and then System.IO.File.ReadAllText to read the contents of the file into your textbox.

Comment: Yes, but how would I specify which file to open?